# Office scripts does not allow getting data from private github repo with acces token

Tags: excel, github, office-scripts

In office scripts, I am trying to access csv files from a private Github repository. For this I use the following fetch call:

```
let token = "TOKEN"
const headers = {
  "Authorization": `token ${token}`
}
let url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ORGANISATION/REPO/main/data/example.csv
const res = await fetch(url, { headers });
```

When I inspect the browser dev tools I see the following error:

```
Access to fetch at "{github url}" from origin '{officescripts_url}.officescripts.microsoftusercontent.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

My office script console tells me this (I replaced some urls just to be sure):

```
{message: "Failed to fetch", name: "TypeError", stack: "TypeError: Failed to fetch at self.fetch  ({url}) at importCSV ({url}) at async main (blob:{url}) at async _____wrapperMain (blob:{url})"}
```

When I put the same request in Insomnia, I can get my data without problems.

Is there a way to fix or work around this issue in Office scripts?

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch text files from both private and public GitHub repositories.

### Get the URL for the file

1. On Github click the file in the repository
2. click `raw`
3. Copy the whole url in the address bar

   - For private repositories you need to make sure to include the token in the URL: `?token=...`

### Example URLs

#### public

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wandyezj/data/master/lists/shapes.list.txt`

#### private

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wandyezj/simple-website/master/LICENSE?token=GHSAT0AAAAAACJUEK6DGRAUMSQW3WZA6YLMZKD2B3A`

### Example Office Script

```
/**
 * Script to show how to fetch public text file data from GitHub and insert it into a worksheet.
 */
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

    // Read a text file on github
    // This file contains a list of shapes
    const request = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wandyezj/data/master/lists/shapes.list.txt")
    const text = await request.text();
    console.log(text);

    // Insert into new worksheet
    const rows = text.split("\n").map(x => [x])
    workbook.addWorksheet().getRange(`A1:A${rows.length}`).setValues(rows);
}
```

Comment: This is great, except that it seems like the token for my raw file changes whenever I request it from the office script. If I use the url with the token from my browser or Insomnia, I can keep using it. However when I request it from office scripts, it does only work once, after that I have to manually get the token, which then has changed.